# JasperserverRestClient

Tags: java, jasper

Boa noite estou usando o JasperserverRestClient para recuperar um relatório do jasper server, porém quando tento usar o ReportExecutionDescriptor ele está null.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
RestClientConfiguration configuration = new RestClientConfiguration("https://xxx/jasperserver");
        JasperserverRestClient client = new JasperserverRestClient(configuration);
        Session session = client.authenticate("xxx", "xxx");

        ReportExecutionRequest request = new ReportExecutionRequest();
        request.setReportUnitUri("/rest_v2/reports/sistemas/guia_tiss/spsadt");
        request.setAsync(Boolean.FALSE);
        request.setOutputFormat(ReportOutputFormat.HTML);  

            OperationResult<ReportExecutionDescriptor> operationResult = session.reportingService().newReportExecutionRequest(request);
        ReportExecutionDescriptor reportExecutionDescriptor = operationResult.getEntity();
```